# Create a Ubuntu PPA with C# (.NET Core)?

Tags: apt, compiling, ppa, launchpad, sdk

Is it possible to create Launchpad PPAs with C# (.NET Core) ? 
I mean, I have to upload the sources to launchpad somewhere, and then create a makefile like

```
$ echo -e 'BINDIR := /usr/bin

all:
\tgcc main.c -o my_hello_world

install:
\tmkdir -p ${DESTDIR}${BINDIR}
\tcp my_hello_world ${DESTDIR}${BINDIR}/
' > Makefile
```

but then I have to write in the makefile something like

```
all: 
\tdotnet restore -r linux-x64
\tdotnet build -r linux-x64
\tdotnet publish -f netcoreapp3.1  -c Release -r linux-x64  /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

and for that, the .NET Core SDK needs to be installed on the building system.

Now the .NET SDK is in a MS repository, that needs to be added manually.

Is it even possible to build something on Launchpad that isn't C or an interpreted language ?

Comment: You can [depend on other PPAs](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/BuildingASourcePackage#Depending_on_other_PPAs). Is the SDK available in another PPA?

Comment: @muru: Nope. So that would mean I would need to create a ppa to build the sdk from source, and then depend on that ppa. Sounds like a LOT of work...

Comment: @WitchCraft did you manage to create a PPA from C# code?

Answer (score 1):

Launchpad doesn't in general care what language your code is written is, as long as you can declare (and provide, if they aren't in Ubuntu) build-dependencies on whatever you need to build it.

Can you use [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/) rather than the .NET SDK?  It's in Ubuntu (with various versions depending on the Ubuntu release), and it [supports C# and a fair amount of .NET](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/).

Comment: Mono ? In short - no.